# NoReverseMatch with unittest

Tags: django, django-templates, django-testing, django-i18n

So it's time to ask my first stupid question.

There are two simple identical tests:

```
    def test_home_page_status_code(self):
        response = self.client.get('/en/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_view_url_by_name(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('web:home'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

There are two simple urls configs:

```
...
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('', include('web.urls', namespace='web')),
    )
...

...

app_name = 'web'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    ]
...
```

And there's a part of code in the template:

```
{% for lang_code, lang_name in languages %}
 {% language lang_code %}
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url request.resolver_match.view_name %}">{{ lang_name }}</a>
 {% endlanguage %}
{% endfor %}
```

If I comment on the code in the template, both tests will pass; if I leave the code, the reverse test will fall.

```
  raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what parameter do I have to pass in reverse to pass the test?

Comment: It is the url you are passing. `{% url request.resolver_match.view_name %}` this is not a valid url for given context. Change this with a suitable one that you need.

Comment: @DenizKaplan if run the selenium test, this template is displayed correctly and the links are correct.

Comment: What's the namespace of your urlconf?

Comment: @Harben 
url_resolver.namespace_dict.keys()

dict_keys(['debug_toolbar', 'social', 'ranking', 'partners', 'card', 'profiles', 'cocktails', 'blog', 'web', 'admin'])

Comment: @Harben or did I misunderstand the question?

Answer (score 0):

`reverse('web:home')` is using the namespace of the URLConf in your app and the name of the url in the pattern in order to know where to go.

Unless your url pattern for home is namespaced with 'web'

```
app_name = 'web' # Namespace
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    ]
```

The reverse will not be able to find where `web:home`

```
def test_view_url_by_name(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('web:home'))
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: The namespace is present in the second file urls.py, I think there is something else here : if you remove the code from the template, both tests will pass. the problem seems to be that when a test loads the template it cannot execute request.resolver_match.view_name

Comment: You have two namespaces named `web` so I think they're colliding maybe